# Google Calendar created using Service Account throwing error on iframe

Tags: iframe, google-calendar-api, privileges, google-api-php-client, service-accounts

Error Message:

**Events from one or more calendars could not be shown here because you do not have the permission to view them.**

Here is the Calendar list view.

```
Google_CalendarList Object
(
    [etag] => "desdHpkENZGECFHdcr5l8tYxjD4/fKIw12Ok_GJADVcrYRFYIkCE_BQ"
    [__itemsType:protected] => Google_CalendarListEntry
    [__itemsDataType:protected] => array
    [items] => Array
        (
            [0] => Google_CalendarListEntry Object
                (
                    [accessRole] => owner
                    [backgroundColor] => #b99aff
                    [colorId] => 18
                    [__defaultRemindersType:protected] => Google_EventReminder
                    [__defaultRemindersDataType:protected] => array
                    [defaultReminders] => 
                    [description] => This is the default calendar
                    [etag] => "desrHpkENZdesrdcr5l8tYxjD4/lllbKwjH1h1w2pZmsMuWm2OZ3No"
                    [foregroundColor] => #000000
                    [hidden] => false
                    [id] => dfredrescr43fgp5ir02hg2ubc@group.calendar.google.com
                    [kind] => calendar#calendarListEntry
                    [location] => 
                    [primary] => 
                    [selected] => 1
                    [summary] => This is summary
                    [summaryOverride] => 
                    [timeZone] => America/Los_Angeles
                )

        )

    [kind] => calendar#calendarList
    [nextPageToken] => 
)
```

Wondering why is it that I am not able to load this Calendar events on my iframe when Calendar has been given owner privileges ?

iframe code:

> <iframe
>   src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?title=Calendar%20Of%20Events&showNav=0&showPrint=0&showTabs=0&showTz=0&mode=AGENDA&height=550&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23f9f9f9&src=fded3gtscr34de5rr02hg2ubc%40group.calendar.google.com&color=%232F6309&ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles"
>   style=" border-width:0 " width="250" height="550" frameborder="0"
>   scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: Have you shared the calendar with the account you're trying to view it? When you create things with a service account, it belongs to the service account. Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22720387/google-calendar-api-v3-not-creating-event-server-to-server-authentication/22726192#22726192

Comment: Thanks.. That really helped ! I am pretty sure this is not covered by Google Documentation..